# How to create Bookmarks in XSL-FO?

Tags: xsl-fo

i have XML with chapters and there can be any number of chapters inside one chapter. how to create a Bookmark for the same.:

```
      1. Chapter 1
       1.1 chapter 1.1
         1.1.1 Chapter 1.1.1
       1.2 Chapter 1.2

      2.Chapter 2
        2.1 Chapter 2.1
        2.2 Chapter 2.2
```

i tried using:

```
<fo:bookmark-tree>
    <fo:bookmark
        internal-destination="toc">
        <fo:bookmark-title>  
         Table Of Contents
        </fo:bookmark-title>
        <fo:bookmark
           internal-destination="CHAPTER/LONG-NAME"
           starting-state="show">
           <fo:bookmark-title>
           <xsl:for-each select="//CHAPTER">
            <xsl:number format="1. " count="CHAPTER" level=""multiple/>
           <xsl:value-of select="LONG-NAME"/>
           </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="CHAPTER/LONG-NAME"/>
            </fo:bookmark-title>`
            </fo:bookmark>
    </fo:bookmark>
    </fo:bookmark-tree>
```

but i am able to achieve two sub-bookmarks:
one with Table of Contents as title
second with "All the chapter's long name" as title.

how to repeat fo:bookmark tag for each and every chapter??

Comment: If you want to repeat bookmark for each and every chapter then you have to use <xsl:for-each...>; before <fo:bookmark> element.

Comment: <fo:bookmark> is not a valid child of <xsl:for-each> hence it does not work this.

Comment: Pls. share your XML and generated xsl-fo with us.

Comment: @user2285584  -- you're getting confused.  <xsl:for-each> is in XSLT while <fo:bookmark> is in XSL-FO.  When processing with an xslt processor, <fo:bookmark> is a literal result element, hence is a valid child of <xsl:for-each>.

Comment: The value of the internal-destination attribute of an <fo:bookmark> needs to be set to the `id` attribute of some element, not an XPath location path (i..e what you tried to do).  Also, the content model for <fo:bookmark> is (bookmark-title, bookmark*) -- it looks like you're trying to put multiple things into <fo:bookmark-title>.