# How to write Xsl for creating bookmarks in a PDF file using Apache fop

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want to create a PDF using Apache fop . The requirement is that I want to create bookmarks in PDF using xsl fo stylesheets .
Please provide me an example of how to achieve this .

Comment: For the bookmarks, you shall use the fo:bookmark-tree structure. Refer to [xsl fo specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/#d2e24175). An example is showed in the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170937/how-to-create-bookmarks-in-xsl-fo

Answer (score 2):

Use the formatting objects for bookmarks defined in XSL 1.1.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e14206

FOP's conformance is shown at https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-object-bookmarks-section

There is sample FO and PDF at "PDF Bookmarks (<fo:bookmark-tree>, <fo:bookmark>)" in the "XSL-FO Samples Collection > PDF Features" at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples#pdf

Answer (score 2):

```
<fo:bookmark-tree>
    <fo:bookmark internal-destination="B1">
        <fo:bookmark-title>Bookmark 1</fo:bookmark-title>
    </fo:bookmark>
</fo:bookmark-tree>



<fo:block id="B1">
...
</fo:block>
```